How to show metrics broken down by dimensions on the dashboard?
I have the app sending metrics to the Application Insights. It sends the same metric name with different custom dimensions

I want to show these numbers on the chart. I create a new dashboard, add chart there, choose my ApplicationInsights instance and find my metric there. As a result I see the following

It looks like it shows me the sum of all the dimensions. But along with the sum, I want to see different dimensions (gen0, gen1, gen2, etc.).
"Apply splitting" button is inactive. If I hover cursor over it, it says

The question is: how can I show metrics broken down by dimensions on the chart?

Apply splitting in Metrics section will be enabled once you select the metric. I am able to enable the `Add Splitting option.Image.The warning clearly says that the selected metrics cannot be splitted.Check with another metric once.

For the same metrics when I select it under Log-based metrics, Apply splitting is enabled.But it is disabled with custom metrics name.Image

The thing is that I need to show on the chart exactly my metrics. The metric from the start post is one of the metrics I need to show.

If I select my metric under Log-based metrics, "Apply splitting" button is still unavailable https://ibb.co/f1Gy0ht

Are you using free subscription?

This is a company subscription, it is paid.

Are you still facing the issue? @VolodymyrV.


How can I show metrics broken down by dimensions on the chart?

Viewing broken down custom metrics will only be shown by selecting Log based metrics >> custom as shown below.
In order to view the custom metrics with dimensions, the
custom metrics (preview) under Usage and estimated costs must be enabled on the Application Insights instance in the below manner.

Once it is enabled, I have tried below sample custom metrics query in my environment and was able to apply splitting by selecting custom >> HeartbeatState under Log based metrics.

Dashboard:


Note: By default, the Dashboard mechanism will not let the users apply splitting directly by choosing custom azure.applicationinsights instance as shown below. If you want to view the custom metrics, the above approach would be recommendable.

Reference Custom Metrics MSDoc  and also the Github issue for more relevant information

You. Are. My. Hero.
Thanks a lot!

Glad it worked for you. @VolodymyrV.
